# How to fire function on Embedded YouTube iFrame's end

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

Trying to fire a function at the end of an embedded YouTube iFrame's end.  Just need to know how to find the end - after that I am good.

Comment: iFrame's end? Do you mean the edge of the iframe, the end of the video? There is an event triggered at the end of a video, if that's what you're asking. See the docs for how to register an event handler. https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I came up with to use on an IFrame... The jQuery function is one that I wrote for my project - you can switch it out for what you need.  To note: your YouTube video has to have "enablejsapi=1" added to the url.

```
<div class="video-holderYT">
        <iframe width="480" id="ytplayer" height="270" class="videoImageYT" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YourVideoIDHere?rel=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>

  <script src="/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var player;
 function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    events: {
        'onStateChange': ShowMe
       }
    });
 }

 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function ShowMe() {

    var sStatus;
    sStatus = player.getPlayerState();

      if (sStatus == -1) alert("Video has not started.");
      else if (sStatus == 0) {  $('#ytplayer').replaceWith('<a href="page/" target="_blank"><img class="special_hover" src="image" alt="" /></a>')
   //change above function to react to when the player stops.
  }
     else if (sStatus == 1) { } //Video is playing
     else if (sStatus == 2) {}  //Video is paused
     else if (sStatus == 3) { } //video is buffering 
     else if (sStatus == 5) { } //Video is cued.
   }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you want to trigger an event when the youtube video is ending. You can setup an event handler using the sample code below.

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
  height: '390',
  width: '640',
  videoId: 'someVideoID',
  events: {
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
```

Most of that is just template code for setting up a new Youtube Player, but the important part is the `events`, in which you register an event handler to fire for `onStateChange`, which will run the method `onPlayerStateChange`.

Then from there you could have a function along these lines:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === 0) {
    doSomeAction();
  }
}
```

`event.data` is going to be the action that just occurred, and according to the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events), the value `0` means that the video has ended. From there you can perform some action, as shown by the `doSomeAction();` method.

Comment: So if I have a HTML page with `<iframe id="player" width="480" height="270" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/id1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="player" width="480" height="270" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/id2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

and add `function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === 0) {
    doSomeAction();
  }
}`
It will do action at end of either video?  Forgive me as YouTube confuses me. I just want to listen for the end of the video in the iframe without having to add anything else if possible.

Comment: I've never done it that way. I usually create a `<div>` tag, and then just javascript to create the iframe, but it looks like it does work if you create the iframe yourself. I just don't know how it would work. [This page should give you some more detail on how it works.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) That page has example code, including a script on how to get it to work.

Comment: I don't want to set parameters to the videos such as height and what video to play - want this to be driven by the iframes that I put on the page, but I'll want them all to place an image after it plays
`$('iframe').replaceWith('<a href="url" target="_blank"><img class="special_hover" src="image" alt="" /></a>')`