# Collapse iframe after embedded YouTube video ends

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed

I have an image on my page that when clicked, is replaced by a large embedded YouTube video. 
Code here...

```
<img src="/image/data/banners/birthdaycardsbanner.png"/></div>

<div id="thevideo1">
<iframe id="iframe1" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/myurl?
rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0
&wmode=transparent&theme=light&showinfo=0"  
frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
```

And that bit works great. The image is a long thin banner. But after the video ends, it remains on the video screen and I'd like it to go back to the smaller image. 
I can't find how to do it though. Had no luck in searching for an answer or trying out bits. Is it possible to do? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to "remove" your iframe when an video end.

To remove the iframw, simple use this code

```
$('#iframe1').remove();
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cxbeevj/

To fire an event when the video end, please have a look at the following source

[How to fire function on Embedded YouTube iFrame's end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964232/how-to-fire-function-on-embedded-youtube-iframes-end)

Comment: Thanks GibboK. That's quite a useful little tip to know, though I'm wanting it to disappear automatically once the video plays. Where it goes back to display: none. Can't quite find how to do it.

Comment: You wrote in your question "But after the video ends", so I suppose you need to fire an event when the video is ending. Alternatively catch some event when video play or maybe use setTimeOut()

Comment: Yes something like that. setTimeOut() is an idea. I'll look into that. Thanks

Comment: glad to hear it .... if you think my answer helped you with your question, please accept it :-)