# Event Handler not getting triggered on Youtube Iframe Video State change

Tags: youtube-api, owl-carousel

I need the Carousel to stop when someone click the video to play it.
As per the docs, I need to use
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');

The Youtube video is embedded via iframe.
I refered: [How to fire function on Embedded YouTube iFrame's end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964232/how-to-fire-function-on-embedded-youtube-iframes-end)
But, it isnt working. I'm getting warning in Console that webkitURL is deprecated.

Error Log:

```
[Deprecation] 'webkitURL' is deprecated. Please use 'URL' instead.
(unknown) [Deprecation] 'webkitURL' is deprecated. Please use 'URL' instead.
(anonymous)
g
z.Y
n
N
d
v
z
e.zKz
e.bg
wf @ www-embed-player.js:405
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:404
f @ www-embed-player.js:377
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:332
```

Is there a different way to trigger handler on Video State changed?

Trigger to the Iframe container div works if I click in the white space to the left & right of the Youtube video:

```
$( ".item" ).click(function() {
//alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
$('.owl-carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
});
```

But, if I use the Youtube API to trigger handler on Video Play state change, it doesnt work:

```
//This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player1;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
player1 = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
events: {
'onStateChange': ShowMe
}
});
}

function ShowMe() {
console.log("ShowMe triggered");
alert("ShowMe called");

var sStatus;
sStatus = player.getPlayerState();
if (sStatus == -1) alert("Video has not started.");
else if (sStatus == 0) {  $('#ytplayer').replaceWith('<a href="page/" target="_blank"><img class="special_hover" src="image" alt="" /></a>')
//change above function to react to when the player stops.
}
else if (sStatus == 1) {alert("Video has started.") } //Video is playing
else if (sStatus == 2) {alert("Video has paused.")}  //Video is paused
else if (sStatus == 3) { } //video is buffering 
else if (sStatus == 5) { } //Video is cued.
}
```

Currently, I'm testing this on the first video in carousel:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
<div class="item">                   
<iframe id="ytplayer" width="85%" height="220" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/1RA2Zy_IZfQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>              
</div>
<div class="item">
<iframe id="ytplayer1" width="85%" height="220" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/1RA2Zy_IZfQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>  
</div>
<div class="item">
<iframe id="ytplayer2" width="85%" height="220" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/1RA2Zy_IZfQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>  
</div>
<div class="item">
<iframe id="ytplayer3" width="85%" height="220" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/1RA2Zy_IZfQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>  
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shaileshghadge/hoe4jfcp/

Comment: Could you please provide the error logs?

Comment: @abielita updated question with Error log from Console